# Ida, проверка принадлежности функции классу

Tags: ассемблер, x86-64

Как узнать принадлежит ли функция какому нибудь классу или нет,
на примере начала данной функции из графа:

```
var_60= qword ptr -60h
var_58= qword ptr -58h
var_50= qword ptr -50h
var_48= qword ptr -48h
var_40= qword ptr -40h
var_38= qword ptr -38h
var_30= qword ptr -30h
var_28= qword ptr -28h
var_20= qword ptr -20h
arg_0= qword ptr  10h
arg_8= qword ptr  18h
arg_10= qword ptr  20h
arg_18= dword ptr  28h
arg_20= dword ptr  30h
arg_28= qword ptr  38h
arg_30= qword ptr  40h

mov     [rsp-8+arg_18], r9d
mov     [rsp-8+arg_10], r8
mov     [rsp-8+arg_8], rdx
mov     [rsp-8+arg_0], rcx
push    rbp
push    rdi
mov     eax, 2D78h
call    j__alloca_probe
sub     rsp, rax
lea     rbp, [rsp+60h]
mov     rdi, rsp
mov     ecx, 0B5Eh
mov     eax, 0CCCCCCCCh
```

Comment: Чем функция отличается от метода класса? Принципиально ничем. Метод - это такая же функция, только первым аргументом идёт объект класса.

Comment: Так как то IDA определяет что это функция класса

Comment: Мой вам совет: возьмите минимальный код функции, минимальный код класса с методом, скомпилируйте их и посмотрите, в чем отличие :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция просто выполняется. Ассембер не знает, что такое класс. Компилятор языка более высокого уравня (например, C++), генерирует фунцию, первым параметром которой является указатель на объект класса. Он используется для доступа к членам класса.

Проследите за использованием `rcx` в функции, вы увидите чтение/запись по адресам `[rcx+class_member_offset]`. При этом нельзя определить, это C++ или нет, с таким же успехом это может быть функция C с указателем на структуру.

В приведенном примере `rcx` сохраняется по адресу `[rsp-8+arg_0]`. Посмотрите, где еще в функции используется `arg_0`. Это тоже доступ к членам класса.

В дебагере вы можете посмотреть объект класса в памяти, начиная с адреса `[rcx]`. Это начальные навыки хакера.  Пригодится также при отладке оптимизированного кода.